# Go - Comparing strings/byte slices input by the user

Tags: string, input, go, compare, byte

I am getting input from the user, however when I try to compare it later on to a string literal it does not work. That is just a test though.

I would like to set it up so that when a blank line is entered (just hitting the enter/return key) the program exits. I don't understand why the strings are not comparing because when I print it, it comes out identical.

```
in := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin); 
input, err := in.ReadBytes('\n');

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
}

if string(input) == "example" {
    os.Exit(0)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### string vs []byte

[string](http://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#string) definition:

> `string` is the set of all strings of 8-bit bytes, conventionally but not necessarily representing UTF-8-encoded text. A string may be empty, but not nil. Values of string type are immutable.

[byte](http://tip.golang.org/pkg/builtin/#byte) definition:

> byte is an alias for uint8 and is equivalent to uint8 in all ways. It is used, by convention, to distinguish byte values from 8-bit unsigned integer values.

What does it mean?

- `[]byte` is a `byte` slice. *slice* can be empty.
- `string` elements are unicode characters, which can have more then 1 byte.
- `string` elements keep a meaning of data (encoding), `[]bytes` not.
- equality operator is defined for `string` type but not for `slice` type.

As you see they are two different types with different properties.
There is a great blog post explaining different string related types [1]

#### Regards the issue you have in your code snippet.

Bear in mind that `in.ReadBytes(char)` returns a byte slice with `char` inclusively. So in your code `input` ends with '\n'. If you want your code to work in desired way then try this:

```
if string(input) == "example\n" { // or "example\r\n" when on windows
    os.Exit(0)
}
```

Also make sure that your terminal code page is the same as your *.go* source file. Be aware about different end-line styles (Windows uses "\r\n"), Standard go compiler uses utf8 internally.

[1] [Comparison of Go data types for string processing.](http://daviddengcn.blogspot.com/2013/08/comparison-of-go-data-types-for-string.html)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I understand things better now, but when I try your suggestion of comparing to "example\n" it still does not work.

Comment: yeah i just ran yours and when the input is "end" it still prints "Not ending"

Comment: I assume you typed *end*. What is your terminal code page? Can you check `len(input)` and `len("end")`?

Comment: len(input) = 5
len("end") = 3

Comment: I tried a new approach and it is working for me. This trims that extra newline junk off for me before i convert it to the string for comparison. 

newstr := bytes.TrimSuffix(input, []byte("\r\n"))

Comment: It looks that you have encoding issue and your terminal has different code page then your .go file, where you hardcoded a string.

Comment: or i could have just added \r to the "example\n" to make it -------------------- if string(input) == "example\r\n" {

Comment: of course, new line format was an issue. I've updated my response.